# How should I implement a system to block password cracking?

Tags: security

I want to put a measure in place to stop people from trying to hack user accounts on my website. What would be the best process behind this without being annoying to a customer who just needs to try a few passwords to remember?

I notice Google shows up a captcha image after a couple of failed attempts. I've never tried hard enough but I'm sure they must block you after quite a few attempts.

Would would be the best practice to ensure that someone doesn't try a brute force approach to gain access to an account?

captcha ?
Blocking their IP Address (does this work if they're on a shared IP)?

Comment: blocking a shared ip blocks everyone using that ip. no big deal if it's a home broadband address, bad if it's one of AOL's proxies.

Comment: Use IP blocking against IP addresses that hit some sort of honeypot (e.g., if you aren't using phpMyAdmin, make _any_ attempt to access it trigger the block, which would be OK; no normal user should ever try to poke their nose into that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to lock out(10min, 15min, etc...) on a per-username basis with a relatively high number of tries possible(10 or 20 or so) in a set period(e.g. rolling 30min window). By setting the number of tries higher than 3 or 5, the average user will either give up or attempt to reset their password before the lockout hits.

You may consider logging failed attempt data(IP, username, timestamps, ...) to understand behavior differences between normal user behavior and brute force attempts. This will allow you to refine your policy over time.

Also consider a strong password policy(at minimum 8+ characters with at least one number).

You may also consider some form of multi-factor authentication. You mentioned captcha but there are many other techniques you may find useful. One site I work with will email a token to a user's email address if they do not recognize a user's IP address and the user must present that token before they are able to access from the new IP address.

Comment: By strong password policy you mean a "strong" password policy? As in, doesn't actually know what the number of bits of entropy in the password really are?

Comment: This sounds like a sensible way to approach it especially on a username basis rather than IP. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Schemes that lock a user out after a certain number of attempts and/or extend the time that it takes after further login attempts are accepted again are certainly a good idea. As are CAPTCHAs (aside from being annoying :) *But*, in my opinion, they only make sense if you have strong hardware backing you.

The reason why I believe this should only be tried if you have the resources to do so is that you have to keep in mind that a scheme like that requires you to *remember* the attempts recently made for potentially *every* user in your system. Certainly, there are numerous ways of persisting the information, varying in their effectiveness: in-memory cache, database, etc.

But no matter what, such a mechanism will put additional load on your application, and there's the downside: if an attacker gets bored or annoyed by your app, they might as well try to take it down with a denial of service attack. And complicated login schemes that need to persist a lot of information will help a lot in achieving that goal.

If you decide to apply such a feature, I would recommend you stress test it a lot in a lab first to get a feeling for "how much you can take" - this way you'll find out if you need to upgrade your hardware :)

An easier way that can do without the need for persistence is to apply a password hash like PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt. These artificially slow attackers down enough to make it as hard as possible for them. But be aware, that these, too, put additional computational strain on your application (although presumably less than the aforementioned measures), so again I would do some stress tests first.